# How does Rails process images uploaded by a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Very simple question.. strangely can't find any intuitive answers anywhere.

I got a HTML form with  which allows users to upload an image.

When this form is submitted and goes to a Rails controller, how do I get the image? Suppose I want it in base64.

When I do:

image = params["image"]. I just get a filename... but where is this file? is it in my server? How do I then convert this to base64? I guess the conversion is easy once I know where this file actually is in my server...

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776252/rails-3-upload-files-to-public-directory).

Comment: @BenLee The [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files) disagrees, and the post was for Rails 3. Not that we know which version the OP is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params['image']` should be an instance of [`Rack::Multipart::UploadedFile`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/multipart/uploaded_file.rb), so you should be able to access the path on disk by doing `params['image'].path`.

P.S.: To save a character, most prefer to use symbols since most Rails hashes are `HashWithIndifferentAccess` and can be accessed using a symbol or a key. So `params[:image].path` :-)