# How do I upload files in Rails without plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am extremely new to rails and I have been looking all over on how to upload a file to a directory in Rails I found this [Upload Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9568753/how-to-upload-files-in-rails) but I don't really understand it and I can't get it to work.

This is my View:

```
<%= form_for :upload, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :my_file %>
  <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

This is my Controller:

```
def upload
  path = File.join("public/folder", upload["datafile"].original_filename)
  File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload["datafile"].read) }
end
```

I have also tried the Upload file section of [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)

It says Stack level too deep, can somebody please help and try and explain this to me as simply as possible?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776252/rails-3-upload-files-to-public-directory/25125469#25125469

Answer (score 0):

uploading in ROR similar

```
name =  upload['datafile'].original_filename
directory = "public/data"
# create the file path
path = File.join(directory, name)
upload_file = File.new(upload['datafile'], "rb").read
# write the file
File.open(path, "wb") {|f| f.write(upload_file) };
```

use this it may be help you...........

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's still not working I'm afraid, can you please explain this part please name =  upload['datafile'].original_filename