# Ruby on Rails: Multiple upload using simple file_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails application need to have multiple file upload function which let the user select multiple files in a single file browser instead of provide them multiple file_field.

However my work is fine only for single file upload but for multiple files upload, only one file is uploaded.

Could I pass all the file objects to ruby? If possible, I don't want any plugins because a simple interface is enough for me. I only need to simple pass the files from client to the server side so I do not use any models. Thanks for your help!

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag 'file_upload/upload', :multipart => true, :remote => true do %>
<%= file_field_tag "file", :id => "filesID", :multiple => true %><br/>
<%= submit_tag "Submit", :onclick => "return checkSize();"%>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
def upload
  file = params["file"]
  name = file.original_filename
  File.open(File.join("public/data/001", name), "wb") { |f| f.write(file.read) }    
end
```

Comment: How are you storing the relation without using models ?

Comment: It just simple upload a file to a directory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776252/rails-3-upload-files-to-public-directory