# Download image from database to project folder with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I want to download an image stored in database with paperclip and put it in my project folder. In app/assets/images for example.

Why? : Because I want to put image in a Word. So when I use `docx_replace` or `caracal` gem I cant put directly image within the variable from database (that don't work). But I can put image directly from folder. So I want to put the image from DB to folder, put in the Word and delete it after insertion. That's why. But if you have another technique tell me.

Do you now a way in order to do that ?

Comment: Is this action triggered by a button press or something? Are you using paperclip with S3 or are you storing files locally?

Comment: I store file locally. Yes I click on a button that construct a word and download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you store your files locally and paperclip provides helpers to the full path of the file, you can just use Ruby `FileUtils` to copy the file to the `public` directory in your action. You don't need to download it, because it is already in the filesystem.
This answer provides some base code for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5776577/1023609